# Transitioning to Python from Mathematica

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica

I have the following piece of code to plot "resonance lines":

```
TuneDiagram[MyOrder_, MyColor_] := Module[{},
  myLines = 
   Partition[
    Flatten[Table[{{A -> a, B -> +MyOrder - a, C -> p}, {A -> a, 
        B -> -MyOrder + a, C -> p}}, {a, 0, MyOrder}, {p, -MyOrder, 
       MyOrder}]], 3];
  myEquation = A  x + B y == C /. myLines;
  ContourPlot[Evaluate[myEquation], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
   ContourStyle -> MyColor, PlotRangePadding -> None, 
   GridLines -> None, 
   ]]
```

I can obtain plots likes this one.

I would like to get the same result using `Python` / `matplotlib`.

I'm totally confused by the "translation" of this programming style onto Python. Any pointer would be much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: this is too compex to know where to begin. `ContourPlot` implicitly traces out roots of symbolic functions.  Does matplotlib have an equivalent?

Comment: You can convert your contour equations into parametric equations and plot them instead if matplotlib cannot plot the contours. I can post the *Mathematica code* to do this if it will help.

Comment: @Edmund Well that would be of great help.

Answer (score 2):

As per the OP's request here is a method to translate `myLines` into parametric equations. This might be easier to convert into Python.

```
pars = {x, y} /. DeleteDuplicates[
   First@Solve[#, First@Variables@*First@#] & /@ myLines];
```

Use `Solve` and `Variables` to get the parametric equation of the linear functions in `myLines` in one of the functions variables.

Then plot these with `ParametricPlot`. I'm guessing that Python can do a parametric plot.

```
Show[ParametricPlot[#, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}] & /@ par,
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.